# Connecting an ethernet cable (or crossover) at the desktop says connected and at the notebook says cabble unplugged, how?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I have a desktop computer and a notebook.

I have a normal ethernet cable and a crossover cable.

Both machines have Ubuntu 18.04 installed.
On both I configured the IP to be: desktop 10.0.0.1, notebook 10.0.0.2 (both with 255.255.255.0 netmask).

If I connect the normal cable, the desktop says: connected 100Mb/s
but the notebook says **cabble unplugged**!!! (at Settings/Network/Wired)

If I connect the crossover cable, the desktop says: connected 1000Mb/s (yes 10x more)
but the notebook still says **cabble unplugged** :(

I saw nowhere else with this weird problem (one says ok, other says not ok).

The notebook shows only these 2 new dmesg lines after I plug the ethernet cable:

```
atl1c 0000:04:00.0: MAC state machine can't be idle since disabled for 10ms second  
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
```

I tried to disable the ipv6 on the notebook but made no difference.

I can't ping each other.

The desktop ifconfig shows the IP properly configured!

The notebook ifconfig shows it not configured and has some strange values...
These "absurd values?" Could be a hardware problem?
These huge values keep increasing quite fast if I run ifconfig again and again...
**They increase even after I disconnect the cable!!!**
`ifconfig enp4s0 down` and up just after, wont fix it.
obs.: MAC address is shown properly

```
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ...  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8885205001596722  bytes 1110648477732391 (1.1 PB)
        RX errors 7774556523880725  dropped 1110652772683230  overruns 1110652772683230  frame 3331949728115100
        TX packets 5553263863416279  bytes 1110652772706907 (1.1 PB)
        TX errors 4442611090732920  dropped 0 overruns 1110652772683230  carrier 2221305545366462  collisions 4442611090732920
```

I don't know where to look now...

Comment: *"but the notebook says cabble [sic] unplugged!!! "* -- Is that an actual message that is displayed, or your summation?  What is the actual output of the `ifconfig -a` command?  What are (all) the `dmesg` messages related to the Ethernet device (not just two lines out of context)?

Comment: Unplugged status is shown at Ubuntu/Settings/Network. And after I connect the cable, only these 2 messages show up on dmesg. I will edit the question also.

Comment: Since you won't or cannot provide requested information, I vote to close.

Comment: but I did! may be I didn't understand your request? what more you need?

Comment: ah... I will just backup my question and post elsewhere if it gets deleted :(

Comment: Gigabit Ethernet does not require a crossover cable. Not sure if it is causing the issue, but I'd try a regular cable just to be sure.

Comment: @SamForbis yep I tried a regular cable, it showed 100Mb/s. But... I updated ubuntu and restarted the machine (had not done that in a few months) and it is working! something messed the ethernet adapter (hardware?) and it got crazy. I think I I could have run some command to hard reset only the ethernet hardware, it could have worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated ubuntu and restarted the machine.
I had not restarted it for few months now, only suspended.
Now it is working!

I guess something messed the ethernet adapter (the hardware?) and it got crazy (kept saying was sending and receiving data even with the cable disconnected!!!).

**I think if I could have run some command to hard reset only the ethernet hardware it could have worked too.**

Well, now I know the workaround...

EDIT: ugh/blush/shame
mmm... I had this problem in 2017... and fixed it...
https://askubuntu.com/a/932709/589343
detect the kernel module `lspci -k |grep ether -i -C 5` (atl1c here)
`sudo rmmod atl1c;sleep 10;sudo modprobe atl1c`
and it is fixed :)

So, this question is a duplicate? what to do now?